# Flutter how to get brightness without MediaQuery?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, ios-darkmode, flutter-bloc

My goal is to create an app where the user can choose his preferred theme.
I'm saving the user's choice with shared preferences so I can load it the next app start.
The user can either select:
- Dark Mode (Independent from the OS Settings)
- Light Mode (Independent from the OS Settings)
- System (Changes between Dark Mode and Light mode depending on the OS settings)
With the help of BLoC, I almost achieved what I want. But the problem is that I need to pass the brightness inside my Bloc event. And to get the system (OS) brightness I need to make use of

```dart
MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness
```

But the Bloc gets initiated before MaterialApp so that MediaQuery is unavailable. Sure I can pass the brightness later(from a child widget of MaterialApp) but then (for example, if the user has dark mode activated) it goes from light to dark but visible for a really short time for the user(Because inside the InitialState I passed in light mode).

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.recipeRepository})
      : assert(recipeRepository != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<ThemeBloc>(create: (context) =>
        ThemeBloc(),),

      ],
      child: BlocBuilder<ThemeBloc, ThemeState>(
        builder: (context, state){

          return MaterialApp(
            theme: state.themeData,
            title: 'Flutter Weather',
            localizationsDelegates: [
              FlutterI18nDelegate(fallbackFile: 'en',),
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
            ],
            supportedLocales: [
              const Locale("en"),
              const Locale("de"),
            ],
            home: Home(recipeRepository: recipeRepository),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ThemeBloc:

```dart
class ThemeBloc extends Bloc<ThemeEvent, ThemeState> {
  @override
  ThemeState get initialState =>
      ThemeState(themeData: appThemeData[AppTheme.Bright]);

  @override
  Stream<ThemeState> mapEventToState(
    ThemeEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoadLastTheme) {
      ThemeData themeData = await _loadLastTheme(event.brightness);
      yield ThemeState(themeData: themeData);
    }
    if (event is ThemeChanged) {
      await _saveAppTheme(event.theme);
      yield ThemeState(themeData: appThemeData[event.theme]);
    }
  }

  Future<ThemeData> _loadLastTheme(Brightness brightness) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String themeString = prefs.getString(SharedPrefKeys.appThemeKey);
    print("saved theme: $themeString");
    if ((prefs.getString(SharedPrefKeys.appThemeKey) != null) &&
        themeString != "AppTheme.System") {
      switch (themeString) {
        case "AppTheme.Bright":
          {
            return appThemeData[AppTheme.Bright];
          }
          break;

        ///Selected dark mode
        case "AppTheme.Dark":
          {
            return appThemeData[AppTheme.Dark];
          }
          break;
      }
    }

    print("brightness: $brightness");
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      return appThemeData[AppTheme.Dark];
    } else {
      return appThemeData[AppTheme.Bright];
    }

  }

  Future<void> _saveAppTheme(AppTheme appTheme) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString(SharedPrefKeys.appThemeKey, appTheme.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you absolutely must do it like this, you can get `MediaQuery` data directly from the low-level platform object like this:

**Before Flutter 3.10**

```dart
final brightness = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).platformBrightness;
```

**Flutter 3.10+:**

```dart
final brightness = PlatformDispatcher.instance.platformBrightness;
```

However, I would strongly recommend you consider that if you need access to `MediaQuery` from within your bloc, you should instead move your `BlocProvider` to get instantiated after your `MaterialApp` so you can access `MediaQuery` normally.

---

After Flutter 3.10, if for whatever reason you really want to get this value manually **and** react to system changes, you can listen to the `onPlatformBrightnessChanged` event:

```dart
PlatformDispatcher.instance.onPlatformBrightnessChanged(() => {
  final brightness = PlatformDispatcher.instance.platformBrightness;

  // ... Do something with `brightness`
});
```

Though at this point, you really are just reinventing the wheel. The option is there for people who need it, but you shouldn't use it unless you are **absolutely sure** you can't use `MediaQuery`.

Comment: That works! But how can I change the whole app theme if my ThemeBloc gets instantiated after MaterialApp?

Comment: @JustAQuestion It depends how you are navigating to different pages in the app. The easiest way is to use `onGenerateRoute` to wrap every page navigated to in a `BlocProvider` and keep a canonical reference to the bloc in the class level rather than creating it alongside the provider so you won't be recreating the bloc over and over again.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try. And one last question why wouldn't you recommend the low-level window object?

Comment: @JustAQuestion If you pull data directly from the low-level object, your app isn't going to get notified of any system changes. For example, if you have your app set to respect the system theme and the user goes into preferences and changes the system theme, your app wouldn't react to the change. The `MediaQuery` widget does listen to system changes, so if you use `MediaQuery.of` your app will automatically be rebuilt reflecting changes to the system theme.

Answer (score 10):

Starting with Flutter version `3.10`, use the following code:

```dart
var brightness = WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
```

Answer (score 5):

**After upgrading from flutter 3.7, there are now 2 options:**

```
final mode = PlatformDispatcher.instance.platformBrightness;

// With context
final mode = View.of(context).platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
```

**Older, deprecated option**

```
final mode = SchedulerBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness;
```

**error:**
info: 'window' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Look up the current FlutterView from the context via View.of(context) or consult the PlatformDispatcher directly instead. Deprecated to prepare for the upcoming multi-window support. This feature was deprecated after v3.7.0-32.0.pre. (deprecated_member_use at [appname] lib/src/settings/settings.dart:88)

Answer (score 0):

`MediaQueryData.fromWindow` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. You can use `View.of(context)` instead.

```dart
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.indigo,
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: View.of(context).platformDispatcher.platformBrightness,
     ),
);
```